# Focus in windows address bar using Ctr+L

Tags: autohotkey

does anybody know the script (autohotkey) for using Ctl+L instead of alt+D for change focus to windows address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
 ^L::Send !D
 Return
```

Comment: Sending `!d` would be more correct. F4 actually opens the dropdown box (while placing the cursor at the end of the text, but not selecting it), while Alt + D selects the contents of the address bar.

Comment: Yes. I just realized that I needed to remove the third brackets for that to work.